# ItemsSource binding do not update values

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to make list of items. I binded collection of users to listbox. Everything works quite well, but items in listbox aren't updated in real time. They aren't updated at all by this binding. So when I remove any user from the list, listbox isn't updated even if its source is correctly changed.

Source is located in data view model at path DataViewModel.Instance.AllUsers; Whenever I add to this list new item or remove one, layout does not update. Other bindings work well. I tried to update listbox layout, to raise event of source update, other way of adding/removing items, but nothing worked.

I tried to debug binding, but I have too many bindings to find the error.

Thanks in advance for any useful advice.

Listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListboxUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllUsers, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0" Grid.Row="5" Background="DimGray" BorderThickness="0" Visibility="Hidden" SelectionChanged="ListboxUsers_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Code-behind:

```
CatalogueGrid.DataContext = DataViewModel.Instance;    //whole view model added as datacontext
```

DataViewModel class:

```
public class DataViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static DataViewModel _dataViewModel;

    private Collection<UserModel> allUsers;
    public Collection<UserModel> AllUsers
    {
        get
        {
            return allUsers;
        }
        set
        {
            allUsers = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("AllUsers");
        }
    }


    private DataViewModel()
    {
        AllUsers = new Collection<UserModel>();
    }    

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `ObservableColLection` instead if `Collection` wich implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` Interface :

```
private ObservableCollection<UserModel> allUsers;
public ObservableCollection<UserModel> AllUsers
{
    get
    {
        return allUsers;
    }
    set
    {
        allUsers = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("AllUsers");
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct answer, wrong explanation. It implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` which makes the updates work. It *also* implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but thats not as relevant here.

Comment: One other nitpicky thing, its not just "by default". `ObservableCollection` implements the interface. Period. There is no way to make it *not* implement the interface.

Answer (score 5):

For changes to the collection to propagate to the UI, the collection class needs to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

A very useful class that *already* implements this is `ObservableCollection<T>` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Use that instead of `Collection<T>`.

Comment: My ItemSource for an ObservableCollection absolutely will not refresh without the Notify Interface where it is used, and calling notifiypropertychanged in the setter.  It's weird but true.

Comment: @nikotromus Not weird at all. ObservableCollection only tracks changes *to the collection* (add, remove). Replacing it still needs INPC

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!  That really helps.

Answer (score 3):

You have bound your listbox to a [`Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - that is just a list, which does not issue any notifications to bound properties that its contents has changed. Hence, your listbox cannot possibly know when the collection has changed.

Instead, you can use the [`ObservableCollection<T>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms668604%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (or, more precisely, any collection that also implements [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), and changes will be automatically propagated to the listbox.

Note that your property does not *have* to be typed as `ObservableCollection<T>`, you can also just declare your public property as [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); the binding will find out on its own whether the returned class also implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Like this, you are free to replace your actual underlying collection class later on, for example with a [`ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668620%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), in case you want to disallow changes from the outside.

Speaking of this, a note on your code: You have provided your `AllUsers` property with a setter. This may lead to undesired consequences, as you open up possibilities for some other code to set the property to `null`, which (depending on the rest of your code) might lead to exceptions. Unless you actually want to allow assigning new values, for the `ItemsSource` property binding, a read-only property is fully sufficient, as long as the returned collection object implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Comment: On the last point, re-creating the collection (instead of just adding/removing) is a common thing to do, especially considering the overhead of doing large numbers of add/removes. Yes, you run the risk of `null`, but a setter is a reasonable thing to have.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Ok, might be a matter of taste then. I generally avoid setters for collection properties; if at all, I have some method replace the collection instance. But more often than not, I supply my own implementations of the collection interfaces as nested classes, anyway, as that allows for conveniently avoiding that undesirable items such as `null` are added to the collection. In any case, if the whole collection is exchanged, one can just as well call `Clear`, which fires the `CollectionChanged` event in `Reset` mode rather than removing single items one by one.

Comment: Sure, you still have to add all the items (which *may* still be inefficient compared to one giant get). As you say, its a matter of taste to some extent.